# After clean install of 14.04 there are no Nvidia drivers available

Tags: nvidia, 14.04

I performed a clean install of 14.04LTS 64bit on a brand new Intel 730 SSD. The install went OK, but I was not aware that the Ubuntu Devs decided to install (without any warning) the open source Nouveau video driver instead of the proprietary Nvidia driver (as they have in past LTS releases). Once I realized this, I went to the Software Updates "Additional Drivers" tab to install the Nvidia 331.xx driver for my PNY 750Ti card. The driver search came back totally empty -- no Nvidia drivers listed at all! No message explaining what was going on either, just an empty box. I tried changing the mirror from the main Ubuntu US mirror to the Columbia University, NYC mirror and got the same result. I also tried to install the Nvidia driver via Synaptic Package Manager and on a reboot I could not login because no LighDM login screen appeared.  I gave up and went back to 12.04.4 LTS.

I hope the Ubuntu Devs have a good explanation for this new and unwelcome behavior. Is there an way to install 14.04LTS/64 and get the Nvidia driver installed from the beginning? If so, how?

Comment: I had similar problems installing 14.04 and getting it to work with my 750Ti.  Basically, were driver issues with the 750Ti that were fixed in the 334 driver.  I detailed what lead to my solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/454729/installed-14-04-and-nvidia-graphics-card-wont-load/454874#454874

Comment: - you need to update 1st. - " (as they have in past LTS releases)." Ubuntu never did that?! There might be some legal issues if Ubuntu did that. LTS installs -only- open source software.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the command:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
```

This should give you the driver set needed and then just use the apt-get install command to install that driver set.

Comment: Forgot to mention to do this in a terminal window. After install restart the system

Answer (score 0):

Just install the prime driver post-install.  That seems to be the popular move.
http://packages.ubuntu.com/eo/trusty/nvidia-prime

Comment: This may be useful in case you need to purge something along the way: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/using-nvidia-graphics-drivers-with.html

Comment: Please do not just link dump and include the commands needed to this this in your answer.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to use this stack exchange community anymore.  It seems to be too populated with retards.